# Input type for EditText in preference screen?

Tags: android

Is there any way to set an `EditText` in my XML preference screen to only accept number input?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In the xml file:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

or during runtime:

```
editText.setRawInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: I do see your point, but the comments under this answer have been purged. **Mod note** _Please try to keep comments constructive and on topic (e.g related to the post)_

Comment: setRawInputType() is invalid for EditTextPreference. You need to getEditText() on the EditTextPreference first.

Answer (score 24):

`EditTextPreference` supports all the same XML attributes as does an `EditText`. So, use `android:inputType="number"`

Comment: dammit i got all excited about there being an easy question i could answer but you answered it before i hit submit because i was trying to include the dev doc :( anyway here it is (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Comment: It won't let me allow to add float value, any idea?

Comment: @Hello sir, I want add float value like(4.5) then how can I add ?InputType="number"  doesn't add the .

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: Have you tried `numberDecimal`, as shown in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes sir.. Solved that issue using numberDecimal thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Everyone is facing this issue because eclipse is not showing hint when we press the ctrl+space.

Just copy

```
android:inputType="number"
```

and paste. It will work like a charm

Comment: That tag `android:inputType="number" ` doesn't do anything. The keyboard that pops up is still a normal one :(

Comment: Which OS version you are using. Because it is working fine in my google nexus device.

Comment: Min API is 14, max is 17 and I'm debugging on a Galaxy S3 on Android 4.1.2

Comment: have you tried the below code in your java file  editText.setRawInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);

Comment: if it doesn't do anything: try unistalling the app and try again. worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Fully agree with the answer. However I would like to add something here:Once you accept numeric input there is still a scenario where you may get error i.e when a user clicks submit on a  blank EditText. Since you will in all probability be parsing your input to an int or double or float. A blank input will throw an error. I suggest you should check for error using try catch and NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <EditTextPreference
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:key="phone_number"
    android:summary="@string/settings_phone_number_sum"
    android:title="@string/settings_phone_number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I enclose reading preference is try/catch NumberFormatException. If exception, I return default value.

I found it useful when migrating app from say float to int type preferences. Previous installations had float for preference and new one used int.

Of course one still needs to do validation on user entry.